# Firebase database triggers execution delay

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase's cloud functions to execute triggers when a client adds something to the database, but it seems like these triggers take long time to execute.

For example, I have a trigger that adds a creation date to a post whenever a post is added to the database, and it takes like 10 seconds to complete.
Also, I have larger triggers that take even longer.

Is there like a "best practice" I am missing? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Agreed. I have a very small starter DB and I am seeing about the same type of delays. Not very "Real-time" so I suspect we are doing something wrong? I *__suggest adding a code snippet__* of your functions to your post above so more people respond.

Comment: I actually found that Firebase has a "warm up" period. That means that the first time you call a function, it will begin warming up, and it won't be fully responsive until it is fully warm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found that the reason that Cloud Functions sometimes takes time to respond, is because they have a "warm up" period, meaning that the first time you call a cloud function it begins to warm up, and it won't be fully responsive until it is warm.

After it warms up, it will be as responsive as you would expect.

The reason for this behavior is resource resource balancing - If you don't use a function for some time, it will shut down and clear resources so other functions will be more responsive.

Comment: Thanks Eliran. do you happen to know if this is only fo lr free tier or a inherent quality of FB for app tiers?

Comment: It happens in both free and paid tiers, because that's the mechanism of Firebase Cloud Functions. Each function runs on its own virtual server (or many multiple servers), and those virtual servers take time to respond. This is due to Firebase being highly scalable.  I know there are ways around it in Google Cloud Functions (search for "warmup requests"), but I'm not sure it's possible in Firebase. Also, note that if you'll have an active application the servers will always be warm and the functions will stay responsive all the time.